# Xamarin Android: How do i open add header and send post request in webview

Tags: android, web, xamarin, view, httpclient

I have made a webviewclient to intercept the request and adding the header and call loadUrl but unsure it works yet.

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        { 
            var headers = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
            headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + "s2vIKZd_P91MaaxaZ_XyeUpph6wQNrQ81pcQdUXjFTB3r48RaU9");
            view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString(), headers );
            return true;
        }
```

I can load the page with   DefaultHttpClient   but it was deprecated.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine and solve your problem, but if you want to load the page with `DefaultHttpClient`, maybe you want to override the `ShouldInterceptRequest` method in order to intercept every request.

`DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated, we can use `HttpClient` instead, to use this, we need to install the [System.Net.Http](https://www.microsoft.com/net) package in Xamarin.Android project. Then you can for example code like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    var httprequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "relativeAddress");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + "s2vIKZd_P91MaaxaZ_XyeUpph6wQNrQ81pcQdUXjFTB3r48RaU9");
    var httpresponse = client.SendAsync(httprequest).Result;
}
```

Comment: I have it work using httpwebrequest. Thanks for your reply : )